# Configuring Java MongoClient to use X.509 certificate for the authentication

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java, x509

I want to use X.509 certificate for the MongoDB authentication.
How to configure Java MongoClient to use X.509 certificate?

Can not find clear answer here:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do this with the [MongoCredential](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/MongoCredential.html) object and builder. These are passed in as additional options in the MongoClient connection:

```
    MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createMongoX509Credential(
            "CN=client,OU=kerneluser,O=10Gen,L=New York City,ST=New York,C=US"
    );

    MongoClient client = new MongoClient(
        new ServerAddress("192.168.1.1"),
        Arrays.asList(credential),
        new MongoClientOptions.Builder().socketFactory(
            SSLSocketFactory.getDefault()).build()
    );
```

You can also consult the [core driver "tests"](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/master/src/examples/example/X509CredentialsExample.java) which of course has a sample of the listing to test the method.

Comment: Link to test is not working anymore. Maybe this one is better https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/master/driver-core/src/test/unit/com/mongodb/connection/X509AuthenticatorUnitTest.java

Comment: @heroin: your link doesn't work anymore. was it referring to this file: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/master/driver-core/src/test/unit/com/mongodb/internal/connection/X509AuthenticatorUnitTest.java?

Comment: indeed, link from my comment expired